# Form submitting in Meteor with React

Tags: meteor, reactjs

Another day another trouble. I have two collections: let's say `Items` and `Reviews`, items get created by an admin and anyone can leave a review (without logging in). I have an issue with form submitting for reviews. I'll try to keep the following code as clear as possible explaining how it works now and how it supossed to work. Let's start.
First things first, I have a component for a single item with form where a person can write a review (every single item has a form):

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReviewForm from './ReviewForm.jsx';

import {Items} from '../../api/collections/items.js';
import {Reviews} from '../../api/collections/reviews.js';


export default class Item extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <p>{this.props.item.itemName}</p>
                </div>
            <div className="row"
                    <p>{this.props.item.itemDesc}</p>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <form onSubmit={this.props.leaveData}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="input-field col s6">
                             <input placeholder="Name" id="review_body" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit">Send Review</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

Item.propTypes = {
    item PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    leaveData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

As you can see nothing very special (proptypes for items work perfect though), I have a `leaveData` function which I use to reach this component in `ItemsList` component:
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
    import Item from './Item.jsx';
    import {Items} from '../../api/collections/items.js';
    import {Reviews} from '../../api/collections/reviews.js';

```
class ItemssList extends Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const reviewBody = $('#review_body').val();

        Reviews.insert({
            reviewBody, 
            createdAt: new Date(),
        });
    }
    renderItems() {
        return this.props.items.map((item) => (
            <Item key={item._id} item={item} leaveData={this.handleSubmit} />
        ));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.renderItems()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ItemsList.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        items: Items.find({}).fetch(),
    };
}, ItemsList);
```

So the code is pretty straightforward and I use almost the same code to create a new item on admin page, the only difference is that admin page has only one form, but I want every item object to have a reviewing form. May be I messed up with ID's but not sure about it. Right now it works okay but only when I submit a review for the very first item, for further items this form submits an empty document and I just don't know what can be a reason for such behavior. Hope to hear any suggestions to help me get through this at first sight trivial task!

`

Comment: Hmmm, think I get an idea what am I doing wrong. If every single item shows absolutely correctly 'cause I define an uniqe ID, may be I should do the same for every form component? Will try it later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you have multiple Items, all of them create a DOM element with the same "review_body" `id`. There's two things you should do to fix this:

**1. Instead of DOM `id`'s, you should use React `ref`'s.**

```
<input placeholder="Name" ref="review_body" type="text" />
```

`ref`'s are local to the component, and it's not a problem if there are multiple DOM nodes with the same `ref` value.

**2. Pass the `<input>` value as a parameter to the parent component**

```
class Item extends Component {
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let review = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs['review_body']).value;
    this.props.leaveData(review);
  }  
  ...
}
```

Also, make sure you're calling this function.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
```

Now your `ItemssList.handleSubmit` function will get the value of the `input` field as a parameter (instead of an `event`).

You'll need [ReactDOM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom) for this.

Comment: alternatively, use [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) for managing the state of the form

Comment: Thanks man, the information you provided was really useful and helped me to get things work. I really should to pay more attention to documentation after I finish this project though